# Hover event on dropdown items in select2 v2.4.0 plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery-select2-4

I have a little problem with select2 v2.4.0. I need to show popover with text when user hover one option from the dropdown list. The problem is that I don't see any hover like event which could work with dropdown items. In the previous version of this plugin the event was called "select2-highlight" but it doesn't seem to work now. 
I have checked the source to find something similar but without luck. Unfortunately documentation is not complete so I can't check it. 
Have you any idea how I can do that?

Comment: There is no longer an event triggered when an item is highlighted, this was removed in 4.0.0. What were you trying to do that required the event? It might be better if you re-frame your question around that issued.

Comment: I had to display tooltip with a complex explanation about highlighted option (text, images etc.). I dealt with that by downgrading select2 plugin to 3.4 version